# Google Tag Manager GTM - Click Element not firing when contains / matches CSS selector

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've read a few posts on here and have understood that for HTML as opposed to string the "matches CSS selector" option should be used however if you take a look at the images you will see I have hit a dead end.

I have an dropdown tool that, depending on where you click it, different elements are clicked. The whole dropdown though has an ID of lamination-type-picker-0 and so regardless of where I click on the dropdown tool, this ID is always present in the "Click Element".

I need to use this fact to trigger a tag but every time I try it it says that the match hasn't been met in the matches CSS selector

Please help - I'm starting to go mad.

[Names for tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTwv4.png)
[Values for tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fPx3.png)

I've tried virtually all of the options for match types, from "contains" to regex. None seem to hit a match with Click Element.

Comment: I would like to add that I have read lots of posts on this on the forum already and they all say similar things but I have tried changing the match type in lots of different ways unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a div class to me. So my selector will be

[image]

`div.lamination-type-picker-0, div.lamination-type-picker-0 *`

Because you can see, GTM detects the click on the span element which is in the div.lamination-type-picker-0 we want to track.

So I add another part with `*` to match all the element inside the `div.lamination-type-picker-0`

Comment: OMG you've done it - can't thank you enough! I didn't realise you had to add the tag in front of the class!

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me too thanks!

To clear it up, as I still had to play around after reading this:

It's the asterisk wildcard that solves it, at least for me. The specific CSS selector (in this example "div.lamination-type-picker-0") wasn't working, but when I included the asterisk wildcard, it did work because it was then including all the child elements (which when I think about it is actually what was clicked!).